# How to identify UIWebView error by error code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Is there a list of the codes UIWebView returns in `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`? For example "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." returns -1003. Does Apple, or anyone else, provide a list with all the codes UIWebView returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not specifically UIWebView but there are header files that contain network error codes.  CFNetworkErrors.h has the actual numbers and NSURLError.h has the Cocoa symbols.  You should be able to find the versions of them that match your SDK by using Spotlight for those file names.

Answer (score 0):

The list of UIWebView related error-codes with description are available in [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40) or [CFNetWorkErrors enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html).